# ExpressWinston does not log on 200 HTTP response code

Tags: node.js, express, logging, winston

I am using ExpressWinston for logging in Node.js app. Can we log requests for each static resources which are being called ?

Logger does not log if file is found (200), but it logs when file not found (404).
For example, if request is valid like http://domain/css/existingfile.css, Logger doesnot log.
However, if request is invalid like http://domain/css/non-existingfile.css, Logger logs with proper 404 status code.

I need log when file is also found (200). How can be expressWinston configured that it logs for all the requests with whatever status code returned by server ?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

The configuration I have below logs all request in a mongodb database using ExpressWinston and [winston-mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-mongodb), regardless of the status code. You can change the transport to console or file depending on what you want. You will get the relevant meta data for each request and response based on your whiteList.

```js
expressWinston.responseWhitelist.push('body')

const requestLog = expressWinston.logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.MongoDB({
      db: db,
      options: {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        poolSize: 2,
        autoReconnect: true
      }
    })
  ],
  meta: true,
  msg: (req, res) => 'HTTP {{req.method}} {{req.url}};',
  requestWhitelist: [
   'url',
   'method',
   'httpVersion',  
   'originalUrl',
   'query',
   'body'
  ]
});
```

Just replace the code in the transports array with

```
transports: [
  new winston.transports.Console()
]
```

if you want to display in the console.

Comment: Thanks O'Danne. changed logger config as you suggested but still its not logging requests which serves as 200 ok. I need access log for any static files, included  inside template (i.e, js/css etc..). These files do not get called via routes and serves from public directly as express-static. In Apache we can have such logs. expressWinston is not logging these kind of access logs or something is missing in config or so.!?